# How to recreate Chromium/Chrome new tab home page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to find out how to recreate Chrome's new tab homepage with all it's features.

I've tried plugins like [`isotope`](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/), however I've met a lot problems with sorting using the jQuery [`sortable`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#default) class.

I've tried just using good`ol css with floats to create a grid, but it's nowhere close to as good as what Chrome has.

Is there a tutorial out there that covers this?

Any pointers in the right direction would be helpful

Comment: Look at `view-source:chrome://newtab/`. You'll have to filter through the *12,000 lines* though :)

Comment: lol... exactly 12,000 lines is a summer project....to decipher lol.

At least their code looks beautiful and is well commented.

Answer (score 1):

If your using chrome it'll be easier to use the *inspect element* function of the right click context menu. This brings up the developer console showing the *elements* tab. It should also take you to the meat of the layout straight away, without having to scroll through lots of lines! :)

If you haven't seen the developer tools in chrome before, it's well worth getting into! The elements panel will be of particular use:

https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/elements

In short, the elements panel will give you a live view of the HTML DOM, including a view of the CSS classes that are present on any given element.

**Update**

From a quick look at the source myself though, it looks like a lot of it is generated in JavaScript first, i.e. the margins and widths of icons etc are set using JavaScript when you manually resize the page. I pretty sure their layout isn't just pure CSS.

Comment: That's what I've been doing for a while, but there must a faster process. I've spent about a day just removing all the bits of code that don't have to do with tiling

Comment: I guess if you still developing your site, you could always develop it with something like 960 Grid System (http://960.gs/), then grids would be very easy to implement. They also have a fluid version (http://www.designinfluences.com/fluid960gs/) in-case you want to re-size the page.

Comment: Also, this looks pretty useful, I think it's meant for the whole page, but maybe you could nest it in your page instead: http://1kbgrid.com/

Comment: Thank's Andy all the grid isn't so much the difficulty as much as the ability to move icons around by dragging them, and that includes dragging them to different screens and the like.

Also the resizing of the icons as you resize the window is very very useful (for viewing on mobile devices)

Comment: Ah, I see, yeah, guess it gets a bit complicated then. Other than the jQuery UI stuff that you've already seen, I'm not sure what else to suggest! Guess it'll just be a case of developing a simple version of it and adding functionality as you go, until you achieve what you need.